How to use Babel transforms?

The Babel manual sction 1.22 describe transforms. Can someone explain
how can they be used in the code I provide to transliterate sanskrit
using the Harvard-Kyoto method (also in the manual)
1.22 Transforms
Transforms (only luatex) provide a way to process the text on the typesetting level in
several language-dependent ways, like non-standard hyphenation, special line breaking
rules, script to script conversion, spacing conventions and so on.15
It currently embraces \babelprehyphenation and \babelposthyphenation.
New 3.57  Several ini files predefine some transforms. They are activated with the key
transforms in \babelprovide, either if the locale ...

% lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{sanskrit}
\babelfont[sanskrit, transliteration=hk]{rm} [Color=0000FF]{Free serif}     
\babelfont[sanskrit]{fserif}[Color=FF0000]{FreeSerif}
%% For making textsanskrit etc
\babeltags{en = english, sanskrit = sanskrit}
\begin{document}
\section{test उ}

\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{a    A   i   I   u   U   e   ai  o   au =} 

\textsanskrit{अ आ   इ   ई   उ   ऊ   ए   ऐ   ओ   औ} 

{\fseriffamily अ    आ   इ   ई   उ   ऊ   ए   ऐ   ओ   औ}

\begin{sanskrit}
अ   आ   इ   ई   उ   ऊ   ए   ऐ   ओ   औ
\end{sanskrit}

\end{document}


Transforms are locale properties, not font ones. This is quite different from xetex. Here is the correct syntax:
\babelprovide[import,
  transforms=transliteration.hk,
  onchar=ids fonts]{sanskrit}
\babelfont[sanskrit]{rm}[Color=0000FF]{Free serif}  

By the way, if you are not using a right-to-left script, don’t use bidi=basic.

Thanks it worked nicely. Is there any write-up as to how to create aditional transliterations in the .ini files  like transliteration.iast.4.0 = { ([kgcjṭḍtdpb])[h][a]([iu]) } transliteration.iast.4.1 =   { string = {1|kgcjṭḍtdpb|खघछझठढथधफभ} }

Sorry to ask so many details. Does the replacement happen in the process_input_buffer  callback?

Actually it’s somewhat more involved (and internally quite complex). There are two kinds of transforms, those applied before hyphenation and those applied after hyphenation (with some differences) in the hyphenate callback , so we are dealing with the node list. You’ve gotten the idea in your short example, and there is a short explanation here: https://latex3.github.io/babel/news/whats-new-in-babel-3.56.html. See also https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/non-standard-hyphenation-with-luatex.html.

By the way, there are a few new keys in the latest release (kern, norule, and after). See https://latex3.github.io/babel/news/whats-new-in-babel-24.6.html.

Thanks again. Will check the new keys.
